# Deformed pixels in Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to make a 16 bit style RPG in android using andengine, but I am encountering a major hurdle: the pixels always seem deformed and out of proportion(not squares). This is an issue for text and sprites. Here are the links to the forums that have my issues http://www.andengine.org/forums/post37364.html#p37364 , http://www.andengine.org/forums/post35921.html#p35921 . I am using Nearest as the texture option for both the text and the sprites. My sprites are accessed via texture packer and my text is created using code similar to below

```
final ITexture mFontInfoTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(pContext.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.NEAREST);

mFontInfo = FontFactory.createFromAsset(pContext.getFontManager(), mFontInfoTexture, pContext.getAssets() , "LongPixelFont.ttf", 18.0f, false, Color.BLACK);
mFontInfo.load();
```

I've tried scaling the sprite differently, changing the texture option to Linear, shifting the sprite position but nothing really works. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE 1:

This is the code I use that defines the resolution of the app.

```
    // Initializes the Engine and sets the height and width.
    MainActivity.mMainCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    //Sets the engine options
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), MainActivity.mMainCamera);
    //Forces the screen to go into landscape
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

UPDATE 2:

It seems that the deformation is caused by scaling(for the sprites). I did not notice any deformation when scaling by an int, but when scaling by a fraction there was some deformation. The deformation became more noticeable when scaling by an odd decimal (ie 2.5). It also seems that there is a range where the pixels will look deformed. In my case anything less than 2x will look deformed, but any int above 2 looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the deformation could be caused by your ratio resolution policy? If the aspect ratio of your game is not the same as the aspect ratio of the device, some resolutions policies will stretch the GL surface to fill the entire screen. This will definitely result in non-square pixels.

Try using a RatioResolutionPolicy when you construct the Engine and see if your pixels aren't square now. You may get black bars to the sides of yoru game now, but if that happens you now know what the problem is which is good.

Then you can come up with a method to get the fullscreen size of the app and make your ratio resolution policy fit perfectly.

== Update ==

Based on the above comments it appears your question might be the same as:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19075/how-can-i-make-opengl-textures-scale-without-becoming-blurry

It sounds like you are trying to control the scale mode used by openGL. Unfortunately I don;t know where to find these settings in Andengine. Anyone else know?

Comment: See update 1. The problem is that not all pixels are deformed in the same way (See link in op for pictures). The problem is not evident when using Bilinear as a texture option, but in makes the font and sprites blurry, which is not the style I am going for (16 bit).

Comment: From your post on andengine forums: Are you scaling the sprite and expecting it to remain sharp and crisp? Does the problem occur on things that are not scaled?

Comment: See update. I looked at the link and I don't think that is the problem because I am using NEAREST for both my min and mag filters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change pAntiAlias option from false to true.

```
mFontInfo = FontFactory.createFromAsset(pContext.getFontManager(), mFontInfoTexture, pContext.getAssets() , "LongPixelFont.ttf", 18.0f, true, Color.BLACK);
```

It's should help for text.

Comment: I tried that but it does not fix the issue. Also, doesn't anti aliasing reduce pixelation? If so then it goes against the style I'm going for (16 bit).